# Carousel ou Cycle exibindo 6 elementos em formato grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, paginação

No código HTML que segue abaixo, eu tenho uma listagem de imagens dentro de um `container`.
Gostaria de limitar a exibição dessas imagens em uma tabela de 2 linhas e 3 colunas e paginar pra ficar melhor visualmente.

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="pagination-douts">
    <span class="page"></span>
    <span class="page actie"></span>
</div>
```

Já tentei usar o [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) e o [jQuery Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/), mas eles exibem as imagens linearmente, seja sentido horizontal ou vertical.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

**EDIT:**

Um esboço do que seria: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1doqnzm4/)

Answer (score 1):

Você esta tentando limitar a largura do container pai e fazer o conteúdo quebrar dentro dele automaticamente, e assim não vai funcionar com o slider.

Você deve dividir o conteúdo e fazer o slider tratar cada porção (duas unidades uma acima da outra, ou um conjunto de 3x2 por ex) como 1 item ou pagina que ele deve mostrar, por ex:

**2 unidades uma acima da outra:** (mostrar 3 itens por pagina)

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a><br>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a><br>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a><br>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a><br>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a><br>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a><br>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Conjuntos de 3x2:** (mostrar 1 item por pagina)

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a><br>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a><br>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiz a quebra com `<br>` para ficar mais visível, mas você pode organizar no css...